# Script does not work, shows no errors

Tags: php

I made a small script to 'cache' copies of websites, and as far as I can tell it appears to be coded fine, however when I run it in browser, it does not work and shows no errors.

My code:

```
<?php
//Display Errors please
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Get Random String
$length = 5;
$string = "";
$characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; //Thanks for the code stackoverflow
while ($length > 0) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters)-1)];
    $length -= 1;
}
$random = $string

//Get URL from GET request
if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
  $link = $_GET['link'];
  $data = file_get_contents("http://$link");
  //Send the data to the html file
  file_put_contents("/cache/$random.html","$data");
  echo "Cached successfully.<br>Link: http://example.com/cache/$random.html";
 } ?>
```

Comment: you're simply ASSUMING it's working. `file_get_contents()` returns boolean false on failure. you need to check for that. e.g. `if ($data === false) { die("Failed to fetch $link"); }`. you're also simply assuming that the file_put_contents() is succeeding.

Comment: Im acctually assuming none of it is working, since it is not working. Edit: Added the code bit you mentioned and script still does the same thing.

Comment: so start debugging. we can't help you, since the code as written about is syntactically correct. We have no idea what your links are, what your filesystem structure is, what your file permissions are. start checking for failure. put echoes all over to see if the script bails at some point. check return values. blah blah blah

Comment: Question does not work, shows no effort

Comment: I added echos everywhere, and it still does not echo any of them. Page is totally blank

Comment: Page totally blank usually means a fatal error - means the script halts and does nothing, even an echo. What does your error log show?

Comment: Could this '$random = $string' be the problem (missing ; at the end)

Comment: @SamBattat yes, but teach a man to fish...

Comment: I suggest you install an IDE which highlights your syntax. You are missing a semicolon, as mentioned by [SamBattat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1100919/sam-battat). Also note that PHP often does not show anything if the syntax is not correct.

Comment: I usually use Sublime text 2 or Notepad++, but I was rushing this and writing it in an online file editor on my host.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush "I was rushing this and writing it in an online file editor on my host"  - Don't worry about rushing it, Sameone else will do the work for you ;) Glad you're sorted!

Comment: $link = $_GET['link'];
$data = file_get_contents("http://$link"); <— Yay!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code posted,

```
$random = $string
```

should be

```
$random = $string;
```

Its always a good idea to check your php files for errors after you edit them. One way to do this (if you are on a linux/unix system) is to run the php command

```
php -l filename.php
```

You could also use an online compiler (what I did with your code)

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Works perfectly now. Cant believe I missed that. Thanks a ton

Comment: @GeorgeWBush What does your error log state? "unexpected T_IF.."? You REALLY need to locate and use your error log file. It tells you right there what the error is, and you can fix things yourself, and feel like a developer..

Comment: There is no appearent errorlog, how do I find it? Running Apache on Centos 6

Comment: @GeorgeWBush Google something like "PHP error log CentOS 6" :)